# OutOfMemoryException: When trying to iterate through a DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, out-of-memory

I came across a situation that I can't explain.  I turned an array of doubles into a comma delimited string and saved it into a database for later retrieval.  There are about 4k records, and each record holds a string that will create an array of about 14k numbers.  When I tried to retrieve my list of doubles and place them into a collection of list of doubles (ea: List< List < double > >) I got an OutOfMemoryException.  Now, 8bytes*15k*4k = 480megs.  That's no where close to the OutOfMemory limit for a list.

I made a simple test loop in order to troubleshoot the problem and realized two things:

1: If I use this ~500meg DataSet in my method (within the Using Statement), I get the OutOfMemoryException. (if I don't include the DataSet, it works fine)

2: If I un-check the "Prefer 32bit" checkbox from Properties/Debug section.  The Method will finish properly even if I use this ~500meg DataSet

Q1: Can someone tell me why did my method failed when this ~500meg DataSet was present.

Q2: Why did "Prefer 32bit" solved my problem?  I haven't had the chance to test this on a 32bit machine... but my first guess is that it'll fail.

Note: I have a 64bit machine.

[image]

Comment: .NET is probably unable to allocate the *contiguous* memory needed in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Im not sure if thats 500mb of data. but i think 32bit app cant access more than 2Gb memory.

Comment: you just made me realize something.  Is it because the DataSet is ~500megs and the list would be ~500megs, therefore it's ~1gig.. and the Prefer-32bit options is really less then the 2gig limit?

Comment: It can be. Since they dont share same reference means its a copy. But GC should be able to clean all those lists when their reference are gone. Btw you should consider that other applications use memory too.use. Net memory Profiler for your application and see how much memory it takes before overflow.Also notice how much memory you have in total. There maybe other possibilities too which im not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is basically creating 4,000 lists of 15,000 doubles. That's 458 MB of memory used up if you have perfect byte packing.

I can run this code alone in a 32-bit app with no trouble, but if I try to create 14,800 lists of 15,000 doubles I run out of memory.

I suspect that with the rest of your program, and your dataset, and it sounds like you have the numbers in comma-separated strings as well, then you're easily going to run out of memory.

Comment: 8*4*15=480MB (no?).  So, basically... I misunderstood my limits.   Is not that a single  list object can be 2gigs, but the whole memory allocation for the program can't exceed 2gigs.   Right? ... If so... Now I get it.

Comment: @MIJ1974 - `4000*15000*8/1024/1024 = 457.763671875`. And yes, it's 2 GB in total for a process in a 32-bit environment.

Comment: That's the last piece I was missing.  Thanks!